# MySQL - how to read output of "profile query"

Tags: mysql

In the below output, what does the 22.071324 duration refer to - **Sending data** or **executing**?

The natural way to read the output is 22 sec for **Sending data**, and [this post](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html) from MySQL refers to the times this way.  Also, the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profiles.html) does not caution that the table needs to be interpreted in a special way.

So why am I asking this question?  I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863447/mysql-slow-sending-data-phase), which refers to [this post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,241461,242012#msg-242012), where someone claims they read the source code and the 22 sec time should be interpreted as corresponding to **executing**.

Can anyone definitively say one way or another?

```
mysql> show profile for query 4;
+----------------------+-----------+
| Status               | Duration  |
+----------------------+-----------+
| starting             |  0.000052 |
| checking permissions |  0.000007 |
| Opening tables       |  0.000027 |
| System lock          |  0.000008 |
| init                 |  0.000019 |
| optimizing           |  0.000008 |
| statistics           |  0.034766 |
| preparing            |  0.000011 |
| executing            |  0.000002 |
| Sending data         | 22.071324 |
| end                  |  0.000012 |
| query end            |  0.000005 |
| closing tables       |  0.000020 |
| freeing items        |  0.000170 |
| logging slow query   |  0.000001 |
| logging slow query   |  0.000003 |
| cleaning up          |  0.000004 |
+----------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can definitely confirm that 22 seconds should be interpreted as "executing" rather than sending the data. Digging trough the source code of MySQL and talking to several people confirmed that.