# What does it mean when MySQL is in the state "Sending data"?

Tags: mysql

What does it mean if the Mysql query:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

returns "Sending data" in the State column?

I imagine it means the query has been executed and MySQL is sending “result” Data to the client but I'm wondering why its taking so much time (up to an hour).

Thank you.

Comment: It means it's transmitting data from its process to the client. If you're seeing `Sending data` as a step that takes time after you run `SHOW PROFILE` then the time consumed actually belongs to the step before.

Comment: Unfortunately I take a message, The 'SHOW PROFILE' feature is disabled, I have to get MySQL built with 'enable-profiling' .But thank you for your response.

Comment: And It’s additional question. The Query has already finished internally, is it a matter of resources for transmission like network or bus?

Comment: No, you're not listening.. the reason that `Sending data` shows as taking up time is because it's a MySQL profiling bug, the time shown there belongs to the step before, which should be `Executing query` or something similar. It just means your query takes time to execute. `Sending data` step is usually fast, unless you stream hundreds of megabytes of data.

Comment: Perhaps that question could be renamed to "What does 'Sending data' state means in MySQL". It will be easier to find the question.

Comment: @antitoxic I suggested a similar edit.

Answer (score 298, accepted):

This is quite a misleading status. It should be called "reading and filtering data".

This means that `MySQL` has some data stored on the disk (or in memory) which is yet to be read and sent over. It may be the table itself, an index, a temporary table, a sorted output etc.

If you have a 1M records table (without an index) of which you need only one record, `MySQL` will still output the status as "sending data" while scanning the table, despite the fact it has not sent anything yet.

> *MySQL 8.0.17 and later*: This state is no longer indicated separately, but rather is included in the *Executing* state.

Comment: The documentation that further explains that the reasoning is most likely because of a lot of time doing disk access: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/general-thread-states.html

Comment: And what if MySQL is "sending data" while using 99% CPU, with very little disk I/O?

Comment: @RustyX How about the data being already present in buffer in RAM and it is sorting some 100k's or 1M's of rows?

Comment: does "sending data" include the network load?

Comment: @egraldlo: yes.

Comment: @egraldlo based on the code of MySQL Server, the answer is No

Answer (score 27):

In this state:

> The thread is ***reading and processing rows for a
>   SELECT statement***, and sending data to the client.
>
> Because operations occurring during this this state tend to perform
>   **large amounts of disk access (reads)**.

That's why it takes more time to complete and so is the **longest-running state** over the lifetime of a given query.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered correctly, here provides some details in code level(not enough room in comments), take 5.7 since there is no such state from 8.0

Stage `Sending data` starts at [THD::enter_stage: 'Sending data'](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/f091fb09ee1f971af19c39f715e78ef63354907b/sql/sql_executor.cc#L202), during this stage, it includes

1. [send_result_set_metadata](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/ea7087d885006918ad54458e7aad215b1650312c/sql/query_result.cc#L67) which sends result metadata as well as metadata of each fields in result set
2. [do_select](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/f091fb09ee1f971af19c39f715e78ef63354907b/sql/sql_executor.cc#L883) where the real hard work happens, it invokes storage engine to collect data, which involves IO operations

As we can see, `do_select` happens in the state of `Sending data`, the `Sending data` state is actually doing the *select*