# MySQL sum query taking huge time to complete. Looking for a bottleneck

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I am running a simple MySQL query to find total time user spent playing the game:

```
SELECT userId, SUM(time) AS totalGameTime
                    FROM game_attempts
                    WHERE userId = 19599
```

EXPLAIN shows the following:

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE  game_attempts  ref  userId_gameId  userId_gameId  4  const  26880
```

PROFILER shows, that most of the time spent on "Sending data":

```
Sending data    1.786524
```

Why such a simple query takes so much time to complete? Where to look for a bottleneck?

**UPDATE.** Time is INT(11) field, no conversions involved.

**UPDATE.** Possible solution is to introduce (userId, time) index, which solves the problem by moving part of the data to index-tree. But it doesn't solve the bigger problem of why summing up 30000 integers takes so long.

This question doesn't have a simple answer. Indices are right, no time-consuming conversions are involved. It's just about DB eninge tuning — why locating those 30000 records and retrieving data takes so much time?

Important to say that table using InnoDB engine and conains about 2 million records.

Comment: When you say 'huge' time...?

Comment: I belive 2 seconds is a huge time for such a simple query.

Comment: Info on 'Sending data' status : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347193/what-does-it-mean-when-mysql-is-in-the-state-sending-data

Comment: Is it running from a remote server?

Comment: Nope. Running it via php_my_admin on localhost. I mean both server and php_my_admin located on the same physical machine.

Comment: Explain says you are sending 26880 rows back to the user. Don't send that many? Someone already suggested you should use GROUP BY to make it a single row. But if you really need so many rows, then there is no optimizing.

Comment: Try using MyISAM instead of InnoDB (and index userid, of course)

Comment: @Strawberry - that's a terrible advice, MyISAM is often slower than InnoDB and it's a misconception that it's faster, there is virtually no reason why an InnoDB based engine would be slower and MyISAM faster in this particular scenario.

Comment: How is *trying* something like this 'terrible'? FWIW, tests on my rudimentary set-up suggest that such a switch will provide roughly a 10-fold performance on a table of this size.

Comment: There are many reasons not to switch to MyISAM, so it's not a solution here.

Comment: @Strawberry - it's terrible because you haven't backed up anything with actual facts, your only "fact" is testing results you obtained from your local machine and you haven't even exposed what setup it is, how you tested, what the config vars are etc. Besides, there's no factual sign that reading data from InnoDB will be slower than reading data from MyISAM. And to conclude the reply - the actual problem here is sending some 30k rows down the pipe, no matter what engine you use - it still goes trough same pipe. So yes, your advice is terrible and I'm being generous with adjective here.

Comment: what's the result of select count(*) from FROM game_attempts WHERE userId = 19599

Answer (score 1):

try making an index to userId like this will solve your problem:

```
   ALTER TABLE game_attempts ADD INDEX (userId);
```

Comment: It won't. MySQL already filters by userId using userId_gameId compound index.

Answer (score 1):

It suggests you are returning a large number of rows to the client.
Can you add

```
GROUP BY userId
```

to make sure you return just a single row?

Comment: I now realise mysql has special behaviour allowing you to select columns not in the 'group by' clause.  The server is free to pick any value from the group for this column : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

Make an index on userId. That restricts access to records with failing userId.

Comment: It's definetely not an index-thing. I have an index on both (userId, gameId) and EXPLAIN confirms, that DB-engine makes use of it.

Comment: Hmmm, that makes it interesting. Try COUNT(userId) instead of the SUM. The time "sending data" is a bit of a misnomer, and concers reading. A wild guess, unlikely, would be that summing of time involves back and forth conversions.

Comment: COUNT works just great (less than 5ms), but extra section of EXPLAIN contains "Using index". I suggest it just uses index tree, no actual data is involved.

Comment: and COUNT returns 26880?

Comment: So maybe use INT for `time`; @GrahamGriffiths has an answer with explicit conversion.

Comment: Doesn't he want to sum the time spend on a game? `COUNT` is not correct then!

Comment: @DanFromGermany just a momentary test, and indeed summing time seems to be performed amazingly inefficiently.

Comment: No, time is already an integer variable — INT(11)! No conversions involved.

Comment: TBH 2 seconds to read and sum 26000 values from disk doesn't sound too unreasonable.  Also it does sound like a very high number of game attempts, if these are something like individual user logins.  Is this user a special case or do they all have so many records? You could try adding a covering index containing both (userId, time).

Comment: I presume it is the number of individual disk reads that is making it slow, rather than summing the values.  The covering index would help with this - allows it to read all values for userId in a block from the disk, instead of thousands of individual lookups.

Comment: if you have the opportunity to test on SSD, I presume it would be much faster (assuming the disk 'seeks' are the bottleneck)

Comment: Concurrency and table modifications? Did you test it locally with one user only? `OPTIMIZE TABLE`?

Answer (score 0):

In just about any other DBMS, your statement would be considered invalid SQL, because the select part of your query contains an aggregate function as well as a field that is not part of the GROUP BY clause - in fact, you have no GROUP BY clause.

Oracle e.g. will tell you:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

You'll get something similar in MSSQL. 
I'd guess that what MySQL does here is to compute the SUM way more often than needed.

The following query will is more SQL standard conformant and will be way speedier:

```
SELECT userId, SUM(time) AS totalGameTime
  FROM game_attempts
 WHERE userId = 19599
GROUP BY userId;
```

Comment: I wish grouping would help, but it doesn't.

Comment: does the EXPLAIN for the explicit GROUP BY version show it returning just one row?

Comment: I doubt that this will be 'way speedier' - but happy to be proved wrong

Answer (score 0):

Too much precision on your 'time' column?
What if you sum

```
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time)))
```

instead?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that time is just an integer field. No conersion involved.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i note this as an anwser so you cant make this error again

As off MySQL 5.0.23 you can set

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY by SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY ';
```

ur configure the server correctly

```
mysql> SELECT name, MAX(age) FROM t;
ERROR 1140 (42000): Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...)
with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

source (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)