# Data transfer between web/db server

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-transfer

I have a **PHP** script on `webserver 1` located in `country A`. I have a `DB server` located in `country B`.

The php script queries a large table from the DB server, groups the results, and inserts them back into the DB server (to another table). This is done by a single query (INSERT INTO SELECT...)

My question here is, does the data actually *transfer* between the web/db server? E.g. is this using GB's of bandwidth on both servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you never deal with any retrieved data from `DB server`, then the query won't send any data to `web server 1`.  Basically, if you just run the query, the only data that's sent is the text of the query (e.g. `INSERT INTO SELECT...`), which is probably just a few bytes, and then the response, which is just a success/fail value.  That's it.

To say it another way, the data from the `SELECT` part of your `INSERT INTO SELECT` query is all dealt with on the `DB server`, it's never sent to `webserver 1`.

Even if you did run a `SELECT` query on a remote databse, you wouldn't get all of the results back.  You actually get a resource.  This resource is a reference to a set of data still on the remote database.  When you do something like `fetch_row` on that resource, it fetches the next row.  At that point, the data is transferred.

You can test this by monitoring the memory usage of your PHP script at various points in it's execution using `memory_get_usage`.  Try:

```
echo "Memory before query:  " . memory_get_usage() . "\n";

$result = $mysqli->query("your select query");

echo "Memory after query:  " . memory_get_usage() . "\n";

$data = array();

$i=1;
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $data[] = $row;
    echo "Memory after reading row " . $i++ . ": " . memory_get_usage() . "\n";
}
```

You should see a very small increase of used memory after your `SELECT`, and then a steady increase as your iterate over the results.

Comment: That's what I hoped for. However, if I run a `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` on `DB server` it shows a **State** of _Sending data_ for quite a while, hence the question raised.

Comment: I'm not sure what your `SHOW PROCESSLIST` output is (can't understand your comment), but `SHOW PROCESSLIST` doesn't show you information about data that is being transferred.

Comment: See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347193/what-does-it-mean-when-mysql-is-in-the-state-sending-data  'Sending data' doesn't mean 'transferring data'

Comment: Thanks. I suppose there is nothing to worry about then :-)

Comment: @TjeerdKramer I added some info. on how you could test this for yourself.  I know it's nice when you have concrete data--it's comforting  :)

Comment: @TjeerdKramer Did you end up testing it with some `memory_get_usage` calls?  What did you find?  I'm just curious  :)

Comment: No not yet, but I will give it a go on Monday :-)