# How to detect if query is running in the state “Sending data”

Tags: mysql, sql

I read some explanations about "sending data" status but I still don't get if the query is running or not. They say "sending data" means server sending some data to client but I really don't which data is sending.

[What does it mean when MySQL is in the state "Sending data"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347193/what-does-it-mean-when-mysql-is-in-the-state-sending-data)

I run some query using Mysql Workbench and while this query is executing Workbench goes timeout(after 10 min). Then I run "show processlist" command to see if query is continues to executing or not. It says my query status is "sending data".

By the way logs table has 10 million records. So this query must be finish in 10 hours. I just want to know if my query is really executing still?

```
update logs join user
set logs.userid=user.userid
where logs.log_detail LIKE concat("%",user.userID,"%");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it's in the process list it is still running. Your query is just running very slow, I assume, cause you're doing a cross join (which means you connect every column of one table to every column of the other table, which can result in quite an enormous amount of data, therefore I further assume, that your query does not do, what you think it does) and no index can be used on the `where` clause. You're probably doing a full table scan on a very huge amount of data. You can verify this by doing an `explain <your query>;`.
To avoid the cross join specify the connection in an `on` clause, like

```
update logs join user ON logs.userid = user.userid
set logs.whatever = user.whatever
where logs.log_detail LIKE concat("%",user.userID,"%");
```