# How to improve the query with long "sending data" time

Tags: mysql

The problematic query is

```
select count(*)
from t_fault tf
where err_status = 1 and
      report_type = 2 and
      solve_status = 2 and
      fault_code = 8 and
      tf.record_time between '2018-01-12 00:00:00' and '2018-01-18 23:59:59';
```

The profile data for this query is

```
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000070 |
| checking permissions | 0.000005 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000014 |
| init                 | 0.000021 |
| System lock          | 0.000006 |
| optimizing           | 0.000011 |
| statistics           | 0.000080 |
| preparing            | 0.000017 |
| executing            | 0.000002 |
| Sending data         | 0.500267 |
| end                  | 0.000011 |
| query end            | 0.000006 |
| closing tables       | 0.000011 |
| freeing items        | 0.000086 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000012 |
+----------------------+----------+
```

The "sending data" executes about 0.5 seconds,I think it is low performance and i can't do better.

Maybe the index is incorrect.

The DDL of t_fault table at below that contains primary key and index

```
 CREATE TABLE `t_fault` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `pile_id` varchar(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `report_type` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `fault_code` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `err_code` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `err_status` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `solve_status` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `record_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `fault_type` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `solve_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `operator_id` varchar(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inter_no` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `i_fault_common` (`err_status`,`report_type`,`solve_status`,`fault_code`,`record_time`),
  KEY `i_fault_pile_common` (`pile_id`,`err_status`,`report_type`,`solve_status`,`fault_code`,`record_time`),
  KEY `i_fault_operator_common` (`operator_id`,`err_status`,`report_type`,`solve_status`,`fault_code`,`record_time`),
  KEY `i_fault_operator_pile_common` (`operator_id`,`pile_id`,`err_status`,`report_type`,`solve_status`,`fault_code`,`record_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and this table contains 8,944,637 rows.When I execute the following sql

```
explain select count(*) from t_fault tf where err_status = 1 and report_type = 2 and solve_status =2 and fault_code =8 and tf.record_time between '2018-01-12 00:00:00' and '2018-01-18 23:59:59';
```

mysql print this

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tf    | range | i_fault_common | i_fault_common | 26      | NULL | 1584048 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
```

So how can i speed the "sending data" of the problematic query by some tricks.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10347999/2067753 "sending data" is misleading as a label ... : *It should be called "reading and filtering data"*

Comment: Is it possible to speed the "sending data"(or "reading and filtering data") time on my requirements?

Comment: The query is using the index you provided. Nothing I can see can be achieved in the query by itself. There may be server settings that may assist (but not expert in those). The reason for my earlier comment was to indicate it isn't really held up by "sending" particularly as you only have one integer as a result

Answer (score 0):

> and this table contains 8,944,637 rows.

Your table is so heavy. I'd suggest to look at [RANGE Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-range.html).