# Ubuntu server CPU maxed / overloaded / 100% when importer runs SQL query finding attachment ID and queuing them for deletion

Tags: mysql, wordpress, function, ubuntu, cpu-usage

I have been on a wild goose chase trying to find the culprit downing our website. I have tracked it down using `top -i` followed by examining the process showing 90+% CPU usage with `pidstat -t -p {PROCESS_ID} 1`. Lastly I stopped the tracking of pidstat grabbed the TID of the mysqld command and queried it in mysql on the cli with `mysql> select * from performance_schema.threads where THREAD_OS_ID = {PROCESS_ID} \G`.

```
mysql> select * from performance_schema.threads where THREAD_OS_ID = {PROCESS_ID} \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     THREAD_ID: 61
        NAME: thread/sql/one_connection
        TYPE: FOREGROUND
   PROCESSLIST_ID: 36
  PROCESSLIST_USER: {USER}
  PROCESSLIST_HOST: localhost
   PROCESSLIST_DB: {DB_NAME}
PROCESSLIST_COMMAND: Query
  PROCESSLIST_TIME: 0
 PROCESSLIST_STATE: Sending data
  PROCESSLIST_INFO: SELECT ID
            FROM wp_posts
            WHERE post_title = 'https://med05.example.co.uk/in4glestates/{SERIAL_NUMBER}/{SERIAL_NUMBER}/main/LOGO-MA-Roof-Seating.jpg'
            AND post_type = 'attachment'
  PARENT_THREAD_ID: NULL
        ROLE: NULL
    INSTRUMENTED: YES
      HISTORY: YES
  CONNECTION_TYPE: Socket
    THREAD_OS_ID: 8189
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I am aware of the query that is causing so much trouble, and the PROCESSLIST_INFO from the mysql query suggests it is this block of code that is causing so much demand on the CPU:

```
private static function reset_attachments($new_property)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_parent = {$new_property} AND post_type='attachment'";
    $res = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    foreach($res as $row) {
         wp_delete_attachment($row->ID, true);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am not a beginner but this truly is my greatest attempt, I was wondering if there is anyone who can help me speed my function reset_attachments() up to a tolerable level for my CPU?

**Why is this function requiring so much CPU?**

**What is a more efficient way to write my function reset_attachments()?**

As always, if you would like any further information, please let it be known and I am more than happy to help you help me!

**EDIT**:

Thought to append this answer here referencing the `PROCESSLIST_STATE: Sending data`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24626122/10134447

**How can I amend the function reset_attachments() to break it down so it can handle the query in a staggered approach?**

I am happy to sacrifice some execution time if it can bring the CPU load down.

Comment: If you "resetting" the attachments of *a lot* of properties at the same time you may want to consider deleting attachments in batches and not all of them in one go.

Comment: It is handled property-by-property. Which is kind of in batches. Are you able to piece me together a little solution that you would try, @cabrerahector?

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with your query tbh. My guess is that it's the amount of data what's causing these performance issues but without more details it's hard to tell. Not that I'm a database wizard though, just speaking from personal experience.

Comment: Any commands or anything that you would like me to run to help you help me debunk further, @cabrerahector?

Comment: Please consider posting TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_posts;  B) SHOW INDEX FROM wp_posts; and C) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE wp_posts; for analysis of current wp_posts table specifications and indexes.